# Python - How can I make DataFrame plots not always printed at the bottom of a cell output?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, ipython

I am printing a list of DataFrames along with their plots using the following code:

```
from IPython.core.display import display
...
for df in list_df:
    df.plot()
    display(df)
```

The desired outcome is that each df's plot and data are next to each other. However, when I run the code, in the output of the cell all the df data are first displayed and then all the plots of dfs. How can I get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import matplotlib.pyplot and use the show function:

```
from IPython.core.display import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
...
for df in list_df:
    df.plot()
    plt.show()
    display(df)
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks!